# Un controlador por cada Tab - TabPane JavaFx

Tags: mvc, javafx, controller, model-view-controller

Tengo un TabPane con 5 pestañas, cada pestaña tiene un gran numero de controles, lo que quiero es asignar a cada Tab/Pestaña su propio controlador, el scene builder solo me permite agregar un controlador al panel superior (el panel raíz), la idea de esto es respetar completamente el patrón MVC ademas de mantener el código mantenible.

¿Alguna Sugerencia?

Answer (score 1):

te explico un poco como lo hice yo.

En primer lugar, asignamos el controlador principal a la vista añadiendolo en el Scene Builder en el apartado controller. (esquina inferior izq)

Por ejemplo, lo llamaremos TabPaneController y en él definiremos todas las tab que vayamos a usar.

```
@FXML
private Tab tabMonitor;
private MonitorController monitorController;

@FXML
private Tab tabUser;
private UserController userController;
```

Tendremos un método que inicie todos los tab, por ejemplo:

```
public void initTabPane() {
    createTabMonitor();
    createTabUser();
}
```

Una vez definido esto, lo que hago es un método para lanzar cada tab y en él asignar dicho controlador a la tab correspondiente. Importante, diseñar el contenido de la tab en un AnchorPane aunque seguro se puede hacer de otras formas pero para mí fue más cómodo a la hora de centrar la vista en el Tab.

```
public void createTabMonitor() {

    try {
        FXMLLoader loaderMonitor = new FXMLLoader();
        loaderMonitor.setLocation(TabPaneController.class.getResource("AnchorPaneMonitor.fxml");
        AnchorPane anchorPaneMonitor = (AnchorPane) loaderMonitor.load();
        monitorController = loaderMonitor.getController();

        // Para que quede centrado, hago un add en un HBox (por ejemplo)
        HBox hb = new HBox();
        hb.setSpacing(10.0);
        hb.setAligment(Pos.CENTER);
        hb.getChildren().add(anchorPaneMonitor);

        tabMonitor.setContent(hb);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Continuamos con el otro tab:

```
public void createTabUser() {

    try {
        FXMLLoader loaderUser = new FXMLLoader();
        loaderUser.setLocation(TabPaneController.class.getResource("AnchorPaneUser.fxml");
        AnchorPane anchorPaneUser = (AnchorPane) loaderUser.load();
        userController = loaderUser.getController();

        // Para que quede centrado, hago un add en un HBox (por ejemplo)
        HBox hb = new HBox();
        hb.setSpacing(10.0);
        hb.setAligment(Pos.CENTER);
        hb.getChildren().add(anchorPaneUser);

        tabUser.setContent(hb);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Espero que sirva, cualquier cosa me decís. 
Saludos!!!